# Как записать данные в файл?

Tags: c#, windows-8

Пробую как в `Winforms` сделать

```
private MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
{
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
}

var data= GenerateStreamFromString(filename);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(data, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.WriteLine(filename);
}
```

Но при записи выдает ошибку

```
Memory stream is not expandable.
```

Почему то старый добрый `File.WriteAllText` не работать в приложениях для Windows 10. Подскажите как просто взять и записать данные в текстовый файл.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` работает где угодно, `WPF` и `WinForm` с ним никак не пересекаются. Может быть, вы объясните, в чем с ним проблема?

Comment: Пардон. перепутал WPF с приложением для Win8-10

Comment: а где собственно вы файл то записываете? FileStream юзайте

Answer (score 1):

Используя класс [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), записать данные в файл можно функцией [Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.write(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// исходная строка
var inputString = "Text string";
using (FileStream fsOut = File.Create(fileName))
{
     // преобразуем в массив байт входную строку
     byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
     // записываем в выходной поток(в файл)
     fsOut.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```